# Map pinning in react native

Tags: google-maps, react-native

I am looking for a way to capture user click and create a pin on the map view. Does anyone has any idea where can I start, I was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions for your issue.

1. Using RN's native MapView component, there are no easy solutions. You can create a pin when `onRegionChangeComplete is triggered. But you'll get the coordinates of the center of the map only. I've set up a running example for you [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/W3m0Kw).
2. You can use this very well done [package](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps). In this package, there is an `onPress` method that you can use. It'll return you the coordinate of the point you just pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the onRegionChange prop from the MapView component. That's a function that will be triggered whenever the user drags the map. Between that and the annotations props you should be able to achieve what you want.